# suPHP error: not within configured docroot

Tags: php, apache, cgi, suphp

On my Ubuntu server 14.04 I've changed the Apache document root thanks to a symbolic link.
I firstly renamed the original `/var/www` directory to `/var/www-old`
than I created a symbolic link to the new document root:
`sudo ln -s /srv/datadisk01 /var/www`

Everything seems fine except I cannot run any PHP scripts as I get a 500 error.

suphp.log says:
`Script "/var/www/website/html/phpinfo.php" resolving to "/srv/datadisk01/website/html/phpinfo.php" not within configured docroot`

So I've changed some parameters in `/etc/susphp/suphp.conf`

Adding the path to the new document root
`docroot=/var/www:/srv/diskdata01:${HOME}/public_html`

turning check vhost to false
`check_vhost_docroot=false`

but suphp.log is keep saying
`Script "/var/www/website/html/phpinfo.php" resolving to "/srv/datadisk01/website/html/phpinfo.php" not within configured docroot`

I really run out of solution.
Can someone please helps me ?

Thanks